# Kafka producer timeout exception comes randomaly

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using below kafka config for one of my producer, functionality works fine.

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "hostaddress:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,"usertest");

props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");

props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 1600);
```

But I get timeout exception randomly, like everything works for some 1 hour to two hours but then suddenly gets following timeout exception for few records.
In my test run, producer sent around 20k msgs and consumer received 18978.

```
2019-09-24 13:45:43,106 ERROR c.j.b.p.UserProducer$1 [http-nio-8185-exec-13] Send failed for record ProducerRecord(topic=user_test_topic, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key=UPDATE_USER, value=CreatePartnerSite [userid=3,  name=user123, email=testuser@gmail.com, phone=1234567890]], timestamp=null)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
2019-09-24 13:45:43,107 ERROR c.j.b.s.UserServiceImpl [http-nio-8185-exec-13] failed to puplish
```

Comment: Describe your Kafka cluster:

 1. How many nodes? 2. Are they in the same data center?

Comment: I have 3 broker,  yes all are in same data center since it is stg environment

Comment: Let's say you send X messages to kafka then how many of them actually end up in Kafka?

Comment: I had sent around 20000 and received 18978... remaining all were timeout..

Answer (score 0):

Try updating "max.block.ms" producer config to more than 60000ms.

Comment: How much to increase?

Comment: It depends on the application. Most times 120000ms would be good. Its kind of trial and error.